# How can I edit submenu headings using wp_nav_menu walker?

Tags: menus, walker

The whole world of menu walkers is still murky waters for me, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help me here.

I'm able to produce an auto-generated list of menu items on my page using the `wp_nav_menu` function in Wordpress. It currently looks like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array( 
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'start_in' => $post->ID,
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<div class="page-categories"><ul>%3$s</ul></div>'
));
```

[image]

What I'd like to be able to do, is change the sub-menu headings of Face, Ear and Eye to read 'Related Face procedures', 'Related Ear procedures' etc.

It's important that the actual menu items themselves are still generated dynamically, and not hard-coded. Can this be done using a walker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with the help of the menu CSS classes:

For the menu item that you want to modify the label of, add the `wpse_menu` class to it:

[image: menu modifictation]

This is supported with:

```
 /**
  * Modify the title of menu items that contain the 'wpse_menu' class.
  * We restrict this to the primary menu.
  */
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', function( $items, $args )
 {
     if( isset( $args->theme_location ) && 'primary' === $args->theme_location )
     {
         foreach( $items as &$item )
         {
             if( in_array( 'wpse_menu', $item->classes ) )
                 $item->title = __( ' Related ' ) . $item->title . __( ' products ' );       
         }
     }
     return $items;
 }, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Whilst this does work, it also adds the text in the main navigation in the header itself. Is there anyway to only apply to the instance where I use the code shown?

Comment: I think that should work also, if this 'heading' is unique to the ones you want to change. But it could depend where this class is added @Lee

Comment: It's going to need to be a walker, as I don't want it to affect the main navigation (all the subheadings in the top navigation menu also have this applied to them).

Comment: But you only need to add 'wpse_menu' to the ones you want to change, and you can add more than one css class to each menu item, so I don't see that as a problem @Lee

Comment: Yeah, but that will still apply it to both the top navigation instance, and this instance which is further down the page. take a look at http://dev.bellavou.co.uk/face and you'll see (if you hover over the menu items, you'll see the text applied there too..)

Comment: I updated the answer, so this will only target the primary menu. @Lee

Comment: This won't work, because the same menu is being called in both places (they are both main-menu). But i'm using a PHP function to call the second instance, so I can add a walker there... That's why I'm sure it needs to be a walker.

Comment: You can just call your menu (the second instance) with custom arguments like `menu_id`, `name`, `slug`, `menu_class` ... and target those parameters instead of `theme_location` in the above code snippet. You could even use it with your own custom parameter `'wpse_modify' => 'yes'` and target it @Lee